# Segmentation Fault [2D array]

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void input_Array(char (&A)[10][10], int x, int y);
int calc_Collision(char (&A)[10][10]);
void display(char (&A)[10][10]);
void init_Array(char (&A)[10][10]);

int main()
{
  int m,n,test;
  char A[10][10];
  init_Array(A);
  cin>>test;
  while (test>0)
  {
    cin>>m>>n;
    input_Array(A,m,n);
    display(A);
    cout<<"FLAG";
    cout<<calc_Collision(A);
    test--;
  }
}

//Calculates no. of ways to select two 1's in each column
int calc_Collision(char (&A)[10][10])
{
  int count=0;
  int sum=0;
  int select(int x, int y);
  for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
  {
   count=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
      if (A[i][j]=='1')
      {
        count++;
      }
    }
    sum=sum + select(count,2);
  }
  return sum;
}

//Returns no. of ways to select y items from x items
int select(int x, int y)
{
  int fact(int a);
  return (fact(x)/(fact(y)*fact(x-y)));
}

//Returns a!
int fact(int a)
{
  if (a==0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return (a*fact(a-1));
  }
}

void display(char (&A)[10][10])
{
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      cout<<A[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
  }
}
```

## Input Format:

no. of trials

no. of rows (whitespace) no. of columns

row1 (No space, 1's or 0's only)

row2...

## Output:

The 2D array

Total no. of ways to select two one's in each column

## Problem:

The program displays the array fine enough.

But upon coming across calc_Collision(A), the code outputs:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

"FLAG" is NOT displayed.

Still a beginner here, so ANY help would be appreciated.

Comment: The right tool to solve this is your debugger. Debugging is an essential skill, you can read more about it [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What input causes this error?

Comment: Note that `fact` will overflow on inputs greater than 12. You probably need a way to compute `select` that doesn't directly involve the factorial. (Hint: use maths to derive a formula.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Any valid input gives Segmentation fault. Eg: 1 3 3 101011111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int select(int x, int y){
  int fact(int a);
  return (fact(x)/(fact(y)*fact(x-y)));
}


int fact(int a){
  if (a==0)  {
    return 1;
  }
  else  {
    return (a*fact(a-1));
  }
}
```

Notice that if `x` in `select` is less than 2, then `fact(x-y)` will call itself indefinitely. This is because the variable `a` in `fact` will be negative. This occurs when the size of the input array has less than 10 columns, resulting in the last column becoming empty. This causes the iteration of `count` to become 0 in `calc_Collision`. The segmentation fault does not occur if the input has 10 columns.
 Since you are only computing nC2 (N choose 2), the `select` function can be rewritten as:

```
int select(int x){
  return (x*(x-1))/2;
}
```